# how to fetch value from <input type='text' name='mytextfield[]' /> in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addField(){

    var newContent = "<li><input type='text' name='mytextfield[]'/></li>";

    $("#myfields").append(newContent); 
}
</script>

<input type='text' name='mytextfield[]' />

<div id='addmorelink'>
    <a href='javascript:addField()'>add more contact</a>
</div>
```

This is my view code... I need to fetch the data from input field 'mytextfield[]' which is a dynamic field.

Comment: could you give a letal discription

Comment: <ul id='myfields'> 

  <li>

   <input type='text' name='mytextfield[]' />
 
  </li>

 </ul>  i need to save the data from that field 'mytextfield[]'

Comment: you want to save this through `ajax` or normal form submit ??

Comment: Do you want to fetch from javascript or php

Answer (score 0):

when you are posting array data in your controller you should take it as post array like this

```
function add_records()
{
   //this $name is array
   $name = $this->input->post('name');

   //you can use a foreach loop to insert these data to the data base or you can use
   //codeigniter insert_batch function
}
```

Comment: anyone have a tutorial to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$contacts = $this->input->post('mytextfield');

foreach($contacts as $key=>$val){
// process them as you like

}
```